# Basis of the quotient vector space $V/V$

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

Given a vector space $V$, we can construct the quotient space $V/V$.  I understand that there is only one equivalence class in $V/V$ since for every all vectors $v_1, v_2 \in V$ we have that $v_1 - v_2 \in V$.  My question is what can be said about a basis of $V/V$ in terms of a basis of $V$?

Comment: Can you calculate the dimension of $V/V$?

Comment: It has "no" basis. Since its only element is 0, of course here 0 is understood to be an equivalent class.

Comment: @u215: So you're saying that $\varnothing$ is not a set?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm trying to say that the basis is trivial. that's why i added the ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say $V/V$ is the $0$ vector space, so there is only one basis, namely the empty set!

Comment: So what you're saying is that the cardinality of a basis is *not* the dimension of the space?

Comment: I guess you are right :)